# Two phase email auto responder for WordPress

Tags: email, wordpress

I'm looking for an **email auto responder** that has this feature:

1. When user sends first email, they get a response with email **a**.
2. When user receives email **a** and sends second email, they get responded with email **b** - *Only if they have received email a*.

There are many products which can achieve the first stage, but is there a product, that can be linked with WordPress (maybe plugin form) which can achieve both stages?

If you have any suggestions please share (ideally free products but I would be prepared to buy if it's the best solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) account which has autorespond email structures, together with WordPress plugins. You will have to investigate [which one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=mailchimp) suits you best - it is too long ago that I actually did this.

[Edited to add]
There is a [MailChimp for WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/) plugin that only lets you create one form in the free version (maybe that is enough). I also had [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) and Mailchimp working together at the time.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have used mailchimp in the past, but I was completely unaware it could do what I was after. Would I achieve the result using [automation](http://mailchimp.com/features/automation/) feature? I will also check out gravity forms!